# Missing route parameter - param was passed to route() method

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.4

I am having trouble with routing in Laravel 5.4. I am trying to display a simple edit form for a company.

The error I'm getting is

[image]

web.php:

```
$this->get('company/edit/{company}','SuperAdmin\CompanyController@showEditForm')->name('company.edit');
$this->post('company/edit', 'SuperAdmin\CompanyController@edit');
```

How I build link to the route:

```
<a href="{{route('company.edit', ['company' => $company->id])}}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
```

In the controller:

```
public function showEditForm()
{
    return view('super.company.edit');
}
```

SOLVED: Dear god, I've forgot to add the parameter to the `route()` method in the view where I render the form. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Try `php artisan route:clear` and then check if it gives you the same error.

Comment: Tried, the error stays.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can debug the id like `dd($company->id)` to make sure you are really getting the desired id, because if its `null` it won't work.

It sounds silly, but it happens..

Comment: hmmm... What happens, when you hit the `localhost/your-project/company/edit/2` URL in your browser? Does the edit page come up?

Comment: Nope, if you try to access it directly it's still the same error

Comment: Try to make argument optional `'company/edit/{company?}'` and see what comes up, try to debug it like `dd($request->company)` to see if you are getting the `id` from url.
Anyway error seems to be inside of view file, so you should be able to debug it, just before you fire the view. May i see your view file by any chances?

Comment: I had this same problem and this was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to define the key for the route variable just pass it as a second argument in the `route` function. Laravel will automatically resolve the parameter in the order.

Like:

```
route('company.edit',  $company->id);
```

Hope it would help.

Comment: I've tried that too and it didn't work. In both cases when I look at the URL the parameter is there but error still occurring.

Comment: @Danijelb Then are you sure you haven't used the same route anywhere else? In navigation, header etc.

Comment: No, this is a first time I've added this one. It's simple how routes work in Laravel but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Danijelb Could you please share the complete error you are getting including of file name and line no.?

Comment: Please see the edited question for the complete error

Comment: @Danijelb Try deleting the route() from above line or fill a static value in the function. try a valid Id and see if the error is gone.